# Quotes Surely. Cryptogram #5

Tags: cipher

Answers **must include method of encryption** along with plain text and explanation (explanation refers to thoughts or clues that made you think to do certain things).

---

### Cryptogram #5

> cd, f, mq, ec, dq, tm, ah, ayw, ti, eo, caw, , ajg, dfu, , ens, aqc, yu, , fec, gvy, agk, aic, eqe, , fzo, z, , lw, ai, is, em, abc, cq, is, bvs, , bv, bou, ko, , ciq, fiq, cre, gs, ada, fog, , hrq, bma, aoa, fzo, dr, ke, , fe, abi, , atk, mw, is, , bri, cyw, qi, re, bys, , dbq, adm, , dgy, ep, hgs, bhq, akq, evy, gt, el, bq, y, ra,

---

**Hint1:**

> Modified one of my earlier encryption method (it has been solved). Much easier.

**Hint2:**

> 123♛_abc♕123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain text quote is:

> "mathematics is the queen of sciences and number theory is the queen of mathematics"

The decryption method is:

> 1. The ciphertext is a variation of base-26 using just the letters of the alphabet
> 2. Translate from a-y to true base-26 (1-9-a-p). z translates to 10.
> 3. Convert from true base-26 to decimal.
> 4. Then recognize that each decimal number is a semiprime (the product of two prime numbers)
> 5. The first factors are the ordered prime numbers (2,3,5,7,11...) up to 101, then repeated
> 6. The second factors are the semiprimes / first factors
> 7. Then determine $n$ as the $n^{th}$ prime for each factor
> 8. Translate each $n$ to the $n^{th}$ letter of the alphabet
> [image: Table]

Comment: nope, wrong plaintext.

Comment: many words are right a copule of them wrong maybe with the quote encrypted.

Comment: OK I'll tell you I thought I had encoded not "number theory" but something else, but I haven't verified again.

Comment: nope. just I encoded something like algebra or something else, I remember it was not number theory.